# How to connect to a remote phone using HFP-bluetooth programmatically in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-sco

Is there a way to pair and connect programmatically to a remote device in *Hands-Free-Profile* (HFP) mode?

So far I am able to just connect to the remote device in the normal way through code. I require to connect to the remote device in the HFP profile mode.

Comment: I am trying out the same thing and have some questions like is this method viable to receive call from other phone or do you get only notification? Also it would help me out a great deal if i could get some source code,thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do here.
HFP is a profile, once you have a BT pairing and connection, you can then connect the HFP profile.

HFP itself is not used for pairning.

This is where HFP fits in to the whole of things (from official BT specification HFP_1.6)

[image]

There is more information on how to initiate the Service Level Connection in the official [documentation](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluetooth.org%2Fdocman%2Fhandlers%2Fdownloaddoc.ashx%3Fdoc_id%3D238193&ei=pntbVN-xCIL8aM-cgZAM&usg=AFQjCNF-Hf7fAnmQaItg6WPs7crwoLdVFA&sig2=Xc4Y2mKyW3x8tVVPWbwV5w&bvm=bv.78677474,d.d2s)
Check page 19

Answer (score 0):

In order to do so you need to implemet the whole Hands Freee communication profile (HFP).
Here you can get the UUIDs for Bluetooth server socket identifiers (you need Handsfree and Handsfree_AG) https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothUuid.java

- I would also recomend to read blouetooth core specification
  https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjFs8zr97bPAhXGnRoKHXplDCkQFggoMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluetooth.org%2Fdocman%2Fhandlers%2Fdownloaddoc.ashx%3Fdoc_id%3D229737&usg=AFQjCNFY1IFeFAAWwimnoaWMsIRZQvPDSw

Here is a specification of HFP that you must implment: 
https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwimg6i597bPAhVMXRoKHRUJA2EQFggiMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluetooth.org%2Fdocman%2Fhandlers%2FDownloadDoc.ashx%3Fdoc_id%3D292287&usg=AFQjCNHB_Z4ResJYu7IY5ijZADbGB7Telw